# A workaround to truncating two tables inside a trigger

Tags: mysql

I have a trigger in my database

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `the_permit` AFTER INSERT ON `messagein` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
declare le_center_number VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '0800100200';
declare le_answer VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '0800100200';
declare last_inserted_text VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '0800100200';
declare messageout_count VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '0800100200';
declare messagelog_count VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '0800100200';

set le_center_number = (select center_number from center_number limit 1);
set le_answer = NEW.messagetext;
set messageout_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messageout);
set messagelog_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messagelog);

......

delete * from messageout;
delete * from messagelog;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

and i need to truncate two tables.However truncating  inside a trigger throws the error

`Error: Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger.` and when i try

```
delete * from messageout;
delete * from messagelog;
```

i get this error `......right syntax to use near '* from messageout;`

Is `delete * from messageout;` also not allowed in a trigger?.

Comment: You want to look up the syntax of a `DELETE` statement again.

Comment: I think this says it all `As stated, a DELETE statement with no WHERE clause deletes all rows. A faster way to do this, when you do not need to know the number of deleted rows, is to use TRUNCATE TABLE. ` reading from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Comment: `DELETE FROM messageout`. No star.

Comment: Duh,i sneaky little star.